# Использовать настольный компьютер как BT аудио устройство

Tags: bluetooth, музыка, яндекс-музыка

Можно ли настроить компьютер (ноутбук) так, чтобы он работал как аудио устройство Bluetooth?

Идея проста, хочется использовать колонки с десктопа для проигрывания музыки с телефона. С телефона важно управлять, т.к. есть желание управлять треками с браслета MiBand, а он привязан к телефону.

Comment: В любом магазине можно купить USB bluethooth и wi-fi адаптер рублей за 300-400

Comment: https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a9ea9416404e77/adaptery-bluetooth/?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: Адаптер, само собой, стоит. Вопрос в том, как его использовать, чтобы звук шел с телефона на колонки компьютера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось добиться того что хочу через [Bluetooth Audio Receiver](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n9wclwdqs5j?cid=gambit_devices&hl=ru-ru&gl=RU). Работает!
Из минусов — это приложение из Microsoft Store, если магазин не стоит, то без танцев с бубном не поставить. К тому же, т.к. качается из магазина, надо комментировать hosts файл, если там стоят адреса против телеметрии и прочих сервисов Microsoft.

Также не умеет работать в фоне / сервисом. Если есть желание постоянно пользоваться, надо заморачиваться с автозапуском при загрузке.

В остальном большое спасибо *Mark Smirnov* за прекрасное приложение.